# Is readResolve() required when implementing a Serializable Spring managed singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, serialization

According to Effective Java book (items 3 and 77), if a singleton class `implements Serializable` interface, it would no longer be a singleton unless it overrides `readResolve()` method:

> As noted in Item 3, this class [singleton Elvis class form the book] would no longer be a singleton if the words “implements Serializable” were added to its declaration. ...
>
> The readResolve feature allows you to substitute another instance for the one created by readObject ...

Let's say I have a spring managed singleton class as follows:

```
    @Component
    @Scope("singleton")
    public class mySingletonClass implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Resource private transient Service1 service1;
        @Resource private transient Service2 service2;
        ...
  }
```

Do I still have to override `readResolve()`? Does IoC Container prevent creation of a new instance when deserializing the object? I don't want to end up with two instances of a singleton class.

Comment: Spring - as an IoC container - doesn't serialize the bean it manages. You don't have to implement `readResolve` for that.

Comment: If Spring is not dealing with serialization (which I don't think is 100% true), then I need to implement `readResolve()`. Can you please send me a link to the source of this or elaborate more?